# Sleep function in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json

I want to make api key function using json, the source from textarea #empass 
each email address will be checked on `"api.php?email=mailaddress"`.

And the problem is the request is too fast, how to give it interval ? so each email address will be checked in 3 second

Here's the java script source code

```
$(function() {
    console['log'](domain.com', 'background: black; color: red; font-size: x-large');
    var _0xe4e8x1, _0xe4e8x2, _0xe4e8x3, _0xe4e8x4, _0xe4e8x5;
    $('#start-button')['click'](function() {
        vaa = $('#empass')['val']();
        vaa = vaa['split']('\x0A');
        var _0xe4e8x6 = 0;
        $['each'](vaa, function(_0xe4e8x7, _0xe4e8x8) {
            _0xe4e8x5 = $['ajax']({
                type: 'GET',
                email: _0xe4e8x8,
                url: 'api.php?email=' + _0xe4e8x8,
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function(_0xe4e8x9) {
                    $('#proc-send')['css']('display', 'block');
                    $('#proc-done')['css']('display', 'none');
                    $('#result-container')['css']({
                        display: 'flex'
                    });
                    $('#ygdicek')['html']('Checking <span id=counter>' + vaa['length'] + '</span> account');
                    $('#empass')['attr']('disabled', true);
                    $('#empass')['css']({
                        opacity: '0.5'
                    });
                },
                success: function(_0xe4e8x9) {

                },
                error: function(_0xe4e8x9) {
                    var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('unknown_res');
                    _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=unk_reslt>' + _0xe4e8x8 + '<br></span>';
                },
                complete: function(_0xe4e8x9) {
                    var _0xe4e8xb = _0xe4e8x9['responseJSON'];

                    console['log'](_0xe4e8xb);
                    if (_0xe4e8xb['status'] == 'live') {
                        $('#result-container')['css']({
                            background: ''
                        });
                        var _0xe4e8xc = _0xe4e8xb['country_code'];
                        _0xe4e8xc = _0xe4e8xc['toLowerCase']();
                        var _0xe4e8xd = '<i class=\'flag-icon flag-icon-' + _0xe4e8xc + '\'></i>';
                        var _0xe4e8xe = _0xe4e8xd + ' [' + _0xe4e8xb['country'] + '] ' + _0xe4e8xb['email'];
                        var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('live_res');
                        _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=live_reslt>' + _0xe4e8xe + '<br></span>';
                    } else {
                        if (_0xe4e8xb['status'] == 'limited') {
                            $('#result-container')['css']({
                                background: ''
                            });
                            var _0xe4e8xc = _0xe4e8xb['country_code'];
                            _0xe4e8xc = _0xe4e8xc['toLowerCase']();
                            var _0xe4e8xd = '<i class=\'flag-icon flag-icon-' + _0xe4e8xc + '\'></i>';
                            var _0xe4e8xe = _0xe4e8xd + ' [' + _0xe4e8xb['country'] + '] ' + _0xe4e8xb['email'];
                            var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('limited_res');
                            _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=lim_reslt>' + _0xe4e8xe + '<br></span>';
                        } else {
                            if (_0xe4e8xb['status'] == 'unknown') {
                                $('#result-container')['css']({
                                    background: ''
                                });
                                var _0xe4e8xe = _0xe4e8xb['email'];
                                var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('unknown_res');
                                _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=unk_reslt>' + _0xe4e8xe + ' (' + _0xe4e8xb['msg'] + ')</span>';
                            } else {
                                if (_0xe4e8xb['status'] == 'invalid') {
                                    $('#result-container')['css']({
                                        background: ''
                                    });
                                    var _0xe4e8xe = _0xe4e8xb['email'];
                                    var _0xe4e8xa = document['getElementById']('invalid_res');
                                    _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] = _0xe4e8xa['innerHTML'] + '<span class=inv_reslt>' + _0xe4e8xe + '<br></span>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#result-container')['css']({
                            background: 'none'
                        });
                        clearTimeout();
                    }, 300);
                    var _0xe4e8x1 = $('.live_reslt')['length'];
                    var _0xe4e8x2 = $('.lim_reslt')['length'];
                    var _0xe4e8x3 = $('.unk_reslt')['length'];
                    var _0xe4e8x4 = $('.inv_reslt')['length'];
                    $('#berapaLive')['html'](_0xe4e8x1);
                    $('#berapaLimited')['html'](_0xe4e8x2);
                    $('#berapaUnknown')['html'](_0xe4e8x3);
                    $('#berapaInvalid')['html'](_0xe4e8x4);
                    var _0xe4e8xf = vaa['length']--;
                    _0xe4e8xf = _0xe4e8xf - 1;
                    $('#counter')['html'](_0xe4e8xf);
                }
            })
        });
    });
    $('#stop-button')['click'](function() {
        var _0xe4e8x10 = $('#empass')['val']()['split']('\x0A');
        var _0xe4e8x11 = 0;
        for (_0xe4e8x11 = 0; _0xe4e8x11 < _0xe4e8x10['length']; _0xe4e8x11++) {
            _0xe4e8x5['abort']()
        };
    });
    $(document)['ajaxStop'](function() {
        $('#proc-send')['css']('display', 'none');
        vaa = $('#empass')['val']();
        vaa = vaa['split']('\x0A');
        var _0xe4e8x1 = $('.live_reslt')['length'];
        var _0xe4e8x2 = $('.lim_reslt')['length'];
        var _0xe4e8x3 = $('.unk_reslt')['length'];
        var _0xe4e8x4 = $('.inv_reslt')['length'];
        var _0xe4e8x12 = 'Total Checked: ' + vaa['length'] + ' | ' + 'Live: ' + _0xe4e8x1 + ' | ' + 'Limited: ' + _0xe4e8x2 + ' | ' + 'Invalid: ' + _0xe4e8x4 + ' | ' + 'Unknown: ' + _0xe4e8x3;
        console['log'](_0xe4e8x12);
        $('#proc-done')['css']('display', 'block');
        $('#log_mess')['html'](_0xe4e8x12);
        $('#empass')['css']({
            opacity: '1'
        });
        $('#empass')['attr']('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout` measures time in milliseconds, so 300 = 0.3 seconds. You need to change that to 3000.

Comment: I have try to use setTimeout but I don't know where's it should be placed to make it has 3 second interval each email address checked